# how to implement recyclerview scrolllistener inside a nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

i have a layout with nestedscrollview.inside that i have relative layout with 2 recyclerview and some other views.

i want to set scroll lisntener to one of the recyclerview. i have tried with below code but its not working inside nested scrollview.

xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_deals_show"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutId"
            android:background="#015cb7"
            >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Deal"
            android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchButtonId"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/adPostButtonId"
            android:text="Post an ad"
            android:background="#c44"
            android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutId"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Featured Ad"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adPostButtonId"
            android:id="@+id/featuredTvId"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId_featuredDeal"
            android:background="#fdfbfb"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/featuredTvId"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latest Ad"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerViewId_featuredDeal"
            android:id="@+id/latestDealTvId"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId_deal"
            android:background="#fdfbfb"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/latestDealTvId"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and i have tried from activity:

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                if (recyclerViewId_deal!=null && linearLayoutManager!=null){


                    visibleItemCount=recyclerViewId_deal.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount=linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    firstItem=linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if ((firstItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) && firstItem > 0 && oldScrollY > 0 && !scrollCheck) {
                        dealListShow(pageNo);
                        scrollCheck = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

but my scroll listener not working inside nestedscroll view but working well without nestedscrollview. i have tried with some of SO solution but did not worked,  is there any way to do scroll listener inside nested scrollview

Answer (score 0):

> No need to set `scrollListener` on nestedScrollView instead use ,

```
 yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

and use `scrollListener` on **your recyclerView**

```
 yourRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            // Put your code here..
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        }
    });
```

**Note :-**

Remember to disable nestedScrolling behavior of your recyclerView by

`yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

**Edit**

You can also try it in `onBindViewHolder` of your `recyclerViewAdapter` like

```
  onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
   {
       if(position == yourList.size()-1)
         { 
             loadMoreItems();
             notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
   }
```

Comment: i have tried with this at first but scrolllistener not called at that time

Comment: not possible @AAA first `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` then you have to set the scrollListener..

Comment: i had set setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) from xml.

Comment: try it programatically once.. @AAA and update..because ..i solved this issue using it..

Comment: i did log. calling once while entering the activity.

Comment: @AAA //write your code in `onScrollStateChanged(..)` not in `onScrolled(..)` as i have mentioned in the answer..

Comment: might be your `onScrollListener` is consumed by your `itemTouchListener`

Comment: not it might not be a problem. and i have tried now commenting out that item listener but still not working :(

Comment: okay got it.. **set the layout manager** .. to your recyclerView before adding the `scrollListener` ... :) @AAA

Comment: still same problems

Comment: think the nestedScrolling is what creating the problem. @AAA

Comment: do you need the `nestedScrollView` ?

Comment: or if you are using pagination you can perform it `onBindViewHolder` @AAA

Comment: yes i need a scrollview. how to do pagination in onBindViewHolder ?

Comment: it will be great help if you can :)

Comment: the method i am calling from binder its called for once.

Comment: it will be called mutiple times if you scroll to end mutiple times it will be called multiple times

Comment: i did it inside recyclerview adapter's binder

Comment: log it there and then scroll to top and then scroll to bottom..it will be called again..

Comment: i did for several times but not calling.

Comment: recyclerView recycles view holders(onBindViewHolder gets called multiple times..) ...i have tested it in my device ..its working.. post your latest code please..

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (position==dealList.size()-1){
            Toast.makeText(context,""+(dealList.size()-1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}

Comment: can you help me on this issue please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377114/notification-click-event-best-way-to-show-activity-data-from-service-while-app