# notification click event, best way to show activity data from service while app is closed android

Tags: android, service

i have made an app where i made a unbound service that is continuously requesting to server api, if server send json then notification will show and on notification click i take the user to one activity to show some data. everything working well while apps is opened or background. but when the app is closed, notification showing but  when on notification click trigger to specific activity, there is no data showing(data should come through a server req).

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: what is your fcm version in build.gradle?

Comment: why not use persistent storage?

Comment: i am using unbound service with api call in background